# I can't scrub the Movie set as image texture in cycles

Tags: texturing, video

I want to do Rotoscoping, in the way you do for animation where real life footage is use to inspire the animation of a character.

I almost got it working according to these instructions: [Movie set as image texture not playing in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70425/movie-set-as-image-texture-not-playing-in-cycles)

Except I have to hit in Mapping the Texture button to view a changes of the video texture, that kinda takes care of the problem except I can't scrub the animation which makes it difficult to animate this way.

Maybe it's the MP4 maybe it's the 2.79 version that is buggy I need help trying to figure out why it is not working for me.

[image]

Comment: Roto is really tracing the outline of an image I think that you mean manual tracking? If this is simply related to that question then you should ask in the comments there or re-ask the question with more specifics here. Try changing the title to be more clear. Perhaps include some screen shots to show what you've done so far.

Comment: Click Match Movie Length in the properties panel in the 3D view.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the textured plane to rotoscope from? The background image works fine if you change the input button from "Image" to "Movie Clip", and deselect "Camera Clip". The movie (that I used - yours wasn't attached) worked fine for both scrubbing and playing. The plane would update OK after I stopped playing the video and would snap to match the background image. Oddly, if the properties panel in the node editor was hidden, or if another node was selected (other than the texture node), the texture stopped updating on the plane. This looks like a bug to me that you might like to report (from the menu choose Help --> report a bug). Good luck.

Comment: So I ditched the plane and putting the video on a plane, used instead the Background images and that works. I'm not getting what you have as a bug, me, I can't update the video unless I click on a connector node.

Comment: Check the bug list it was already posted, it said: "Your reported issue has been fixed in SVN" what does SVN stand for?

Comment: SVN standard for Subversion, which is the versioning system that the developers use for storing the source code. So, the bug has been fixed but the fix has not been officially released yet.